# keras will only give accuracy of 0.5001

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm running Keras with a tensorflow-backend.
I try to predict images.

My model looks like this:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(50, 50, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Running my code, it produces this output over 10 epochs:

```
    Epoch 1/10
    24946/24946 [==============================] - 36s 1ms/sample - loss: 7.9693 - acc: 0.5001
    Epoch 2/10
    24946/24946 [==============================] - 35s 1ms/sample - loss: 7.9693 - acc: 0.5001

    ...

    Epoch 9/10
    24946/24946 [==============================] - 30s 1ms/sample - loss: 7.9693 - acc: 0.5001
    Epoch 10/10
    24946/24946 [==============================] - 30s 1ms/sample - loss: 7.9693 - acc: 0.5001
    1/1 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step
    [[1.]]
```

Anyhow, I do not understand why the accuracy is always `0.5001` over all 10 epochs.

My question is: ***Why does the accuracy not change within any epoch?***

Comment: Hello, i have (softmax) have any ide?

Comment: hello, will someone will test it for me? it always 0.5001

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code makes no sense:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
```

Softmax with only one neuron with always produce output of constant 1.0, due to the normalization. If you want to do binary classification, you should use a `sigmoid` activation at the output.

Comment: Isn't it also possible to set two output neurons in this dense-layer and use `softmax` instead of switching to `sigmoid`, is it?

Comment: @Markus yes but for that you need to change the loss and the labels, so I prefer a less invasive solution.

Comment: I see your point. Would be interesting to see how much impact this has for the prediction to use one or the other solution.

Comment: Hello, i have (softmax) have any ide?